# Can I exclude some files from git-lfs?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs, gitattributes

I created a repo with some image files. I have .gitignore and .gitattributes that I want to exclude from lfs. So I need to track all files by lfs but not .gitignore and .gitattributes.

I' m using Sourcetree and I tried that in .gitattributes:

```
.gitignore      text
.gitattributes  text
*               filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

But all of my files getting tracked by lfs.

Comment: Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210453/remove-git-lfs-link-to-file-and-add-it-to-git-directly/

Answer (score 28):

I was looking for the same.  I am using `git` version 2.26.2 and rkedge's answer did not work for me.  I found [this thread](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2120) and ended up using:

```
*.dat         filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
excluded.dat  !filter !diff !merge text
```

For files already commited, I had to untrack and re-commit them after modifying `.gitattributes`.

Answer (score 25):

`.gitattributes` works similarly to `.gitignore` in terms of precedence.

```
*               filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.gitignore      filter= diff= merge= text
.gitattributes  filter= diff= merge= text
```

This will unset the filter, diff, merge for those files, and lfs won't track them.

Comment: This is the answer that should be accepted. I omitted the second line `.gitignore      filter= diff= merge= text` in my repository where I use git to backup my photos.

Comment: I had issues with this syntax using pre-commit-hooks. Using ! as suggested below solved the issue

Comment: After updating the `.gitattributes` file, how do I replace the local files with their dereferenced content (instead of the `git-lfs` reference)?

Answer (score -3):

Unlike a `.gitignore` file, a `.gitattributes` file doesn't have exclude patterns, so there isn't a way to specify that all files except for a few should have a filter (like Git LFS) applied.

You'll need to specify your files in a different way.  If all your files are in a directory (say, `foo`), you can specify `foo/**`.  If they're all images, you could specify a rule for each type of image (say, one for `*.png`, one for `*.jpg`, and one for `*.gif`).

As a final suggestion, if they all start with an alphabetical or numerical character, you could specify `[A-Za-z0-9]*`, which would exclude all of the dot files as well.